# Gauss sum possible typo

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields, gauss-sums

Let $ψ: \mathbb{F_p} \to Z_p$ with the property $ψ(a+b)=ψ(a)ψ(b)$ where $Z_p$ denotes the p-adic integers. Assume further that $ψ$ is not trivial.

I'm trying to follow my professor's work, but I believe he may have made a typo.

> For each $0 \leq k \leq p-2$, define the Gauss sum $g_k= \sum _{x \in \mathbb{F_p}}t^{p-1-k}ψ(x)$.
>
> Let $\sum _k G(k)t^k$ be a polynomial of degree $p-1$ such that $ψ(\overline{t})= \sum _{k=0} ^{p-1}G(k)t^k$ for all $t\in \mathbb{F_p}$

Then, he claims that $G(0)=1$ (which is easy for me to see) but also $G(p-1)=-p/(p-1)$ (which I'm not sure how to prove.)

He also claims that, for $1 \leq k \leq p-2$, $G(k)=g_k/(p-1).$ I believe that this is inconsistent with his previous definition of $g_k$ (after all, shouldn't G(k) be a coefficient instead of a polynomial?) which is why I think he made a typo. Can anyone see an easy way to correct it?

Comment: Something's not right, or I really need more coffee. Is the mappiing $\psi$ or $\phi$? We clearly have
$$1=\phi(0)=\phi(p\cdot 1)=\phi(1)^p.$$ But in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_p$ there are no elements of order $p$, so $\phi(1)^p=1$ implies $\phi(1)=1$ forcing $\phi$ to be trivial. Another thing: what's that $t$ in your definition of $g_k$?

Comment: Sorry! I accidentally typed $φ$ when I meant $ψ$. Ι'll go fix that now!

Comment: But the $t$ in the definition of $g_k$ appears in my professor's paper. I suspect that *he* must have made a typo there, so I'm not sure what he meant.

Comment: Possibly $t$ should be $x$ at that point. I'm more worried about the non-existence of non-constant characters $\psi$. The ring $\Bbb{Z}_p$ has a full set of roots of unity of order $p-1$, but none of order $p$.

Comment: You see, a Gauss sum involves both a multiplicative character and an additive character. A complex valued Gauss sum looks like $$G=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_p}\chi(x)e(ax),$$ where $\chi:\Bbb{F}_p^*\to\Bbb{C}^*$ is a homomorphism between multiplicative structures (thus takes roots of unity of order a factor of $p-1$ as values, and $e(y)=e^{2\pi i y/p}$ satisfies the property $e(x+y)=e(x)e(y)$ (=an additive character).

Comment: To get $p$-adic Gauss sums I think you need to adjoin a $p$th root of unity to the ring $\Bbb{Z}_p$ for the $e$-part (= your $\psi$-part) to make sense.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much for responding! Do you think my professor could have meant $T(x)^{p-1-k}$, where $T$ is the same Teichmuller map I've asked about before on SE?(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988906/existence-uniqueness-of-the-teichmuller-map-for-p-adic-integers)

Comment: That is a live possibility!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $g_k:= \sum _{x \in \mathbb{F}_p}T(x)^{p-1-k}ψ(x)$